# Adicionar Meta Fractal PHP

Tags: php, laravel, orientação-a-objetos

Estou utilizando o `fractal` junto ao `Laravel` para manipular minhas `collections`. Em alguns Transformers utilizo o `available include` (conforme exemplo abaixo).

O que eu gostaria de fazer é incluir um meta com `array` desses `includes`.

Exemplo:

```
meta:{includes: {include1: badah, include2: badah},data{dados...}
```

Código:

```
<?php

namespace apiAneel\Transformers;

use apiAneel\Entities\AccountPlan;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

/**
 * Class AccountPlanTransformer
 * @package namespace apiAneel\Transformers;
 */
class AccountPlanTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    public $availableIncludes = ['acrCod', 'companyType'];
    /**
     * Transform the \AccountPlan entity
     * @param \AccountPlan $model
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function transform(AccountPlan $model)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $model->id,
            'cod' => $model->cod,
            'description' => $model->description,
            'dep_cod' => $model->dep_cod,
            'dep_description' => $model->dep_description,
            'expense_cod' => $model->expense_cod,
            'expense_description' => $model->expense_description
        ];
    }

    public function includeAcrCod(AccountPlan $accountPlan)
    {
        $acrCod = $accountPlan->acrCod;

        return $this->item($acrCod, new AcrCodTransformer());
    }

    public function includeCompanyType(AccountPlan $accountPlan)
    {
        $companyType = $accountPlan->companyType;

        return $this->item($companyType, new CompanyTypeTransformer());
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse factral é um pacote? o que ele faz? Onde é para ser usado?

Comment: Fractal é uma biblioteca PHP, para tratar dados. [Link para detalhes](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/)

Comment: não tem essa opção no pacote, deverá talvez pedir alguma inovação no seu [github](https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal), abra um [issue](https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal/issues), porque no pacote atual não vi essa opção.

Comment: Na vdd tem, mas minha duvida é como utilizar essa funcionalidade junto ao transformer

Comment: Então por favor edite sua pergunta e mostre aonde está... Eu não achei.

Comment: Eu achei isso dentro do link [pagination](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/pagination/) dei uma olhada na classe `Cursor` mas, não tem o que você precisa. Não tem implementação para adição de configurações, pelo menos foi o que eu vi na classe.